# Sheet Selection issue with InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA file with the following code. My issue is that the `InputBox` doesn't work correctly. There are `10` sheets. The first sheet is called "Menu". Other sheets as Sheet 2 - 10. Sheet 3,4 & 5 applied `VeryHidden`. Please help me to rectify it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> "Menu" Then
            Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next Sh

    Dim myList As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mySht

     i = 1
     For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         If oSheet.Visible <> xlSheetVeryHidden Then

            myList = myList & i & " - " & oSheet.Name & " " & vbCr
            i = i + 1
         End If
    Next oSheet

    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(mySht)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Are rest fo the sheets visible?

Comment: Visible sheets only shows on list, issue is Inbox number doesn't work correctly. Also VeryHidden sheets counted I think.

Comment: The problem is `Sheets(CInt(mySht))` When you specify sheets(3) for example. then it may actually be referring to the hidden sheet and not the 3rd Visible sheet :)

Comment: I have posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment above; The problem is `Sheets(CInt(mySht))`.

**Problem**

When you specify a number, say `3`, then the code `Sheets(CInt(mySht))` becomes `Sheets(3)`. But this is not what you want. You want the name after that number as you are concatenating that number with `" - "` and then with the sheet name. `Sheets(3)` actually may be referring to the hidden sheet and not the 3rd Visible sheet and hence you are getting the error.

**Option**

1. Instead of using `myList`, use an array.
2. Split the array after the user makes a choice and then go to that sheet

**Solution**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim ShName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mySht, MyAr
    
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next Sh
    
    Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then i = i + 1
    Next Sh

    ReDim MyAr(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - i)
    
    i = 1
    
    '~~> Store the names of all visible sheets in the array
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            MyAr(i) = i & " - " & Sh.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Sh
    
    '~~> Get user input
    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & Join(MyAr, vbNewLine))
    
    If IsNumeric(mySht) Then
        '~~> Get the actual sheet name using split as
        '~~> we had actually appended " - " to it earlier
        ShName = Trim(Split(MyAr(mySht), " - ")(1))
        '~~> Activate the sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShName).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, It works. One more question is there. This is complicated than above. VeryHidden sheets differs time to time. How to count no. of VeryHidden sheets by loop and that variable we can put instead of "3".

Comment: Check the code now. You may have to refresh the page. I have added that part :)

Comment: Also remember that `.Visible` has one more property i.e `xlSheetHidden` besides `xlSheetVisible` and `xlSheetVeryHidden` so you have to be careful, If you hide any sheet using `xlSheetHidden` then you will have to check for that as well in the `For` Loop.